# Why does the following code give this error: “Cannot initialize a variable of type 'float (*)[in_dim]' with an rvalue of type 'float (*)[in_dim]'”

Tags: c++, c++17, syntax-error, clion

I'm trying to compile a piece of code using CLion.

```
void XW(int in_dim, int out_dim, float *in_X, float *out_X, float *W) {
    float(*tmp_in_X)[in_dim] = (float (*)[in_dim]) in_X;
    float(*tmp_out_X)[out_dim] = (float (*)[out_dim]) out_X;
    float(*tmp_W)[out_dim] = (float (*)[out_dim]) W;

    for (int i = 0; i < v_num; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < out_dim; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < in_dim; k++) {
                tmp_out_X[i][j] += tmp_in_X[i][k] * tmp_W[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
void AX(int dim, float *in_X, float *out_X) {
    float(*tmp_in_X)[dim] = (float (*)[dim]) in_X;
    float(*tmp_out_X)[dim] = (float (*)[dim]) out_X;

    for (int i = 0; i < v_num; i++) {
        vector<int> &nlist = edge_index[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < nlist.size(); j++) {
            int nbr = nlist[j];
            for (int k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
                tmp_out_X[i][k] += tmp_in_X[nbr][k] * edge_val[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are many similar structures like this one, I'm just uploading a segment as an example.
However, all of these structures report errors like this:
`Cannot initialize a variable of type 'float (*)[in_dim]' with an rvalue of type 'float (*)[in_dim]'`
`Cannot initialize a variable of type 'float (*)[out_dim]' with an rvalue of type 'float (*)[out_dim]'`

These codes were compiled by g++, and hadn't any question. The compiler of my Clion is MinGW(default).

Comment: Generally, whenever you feel the need to do a C-style explicit conversion (cast) then you should take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: This is non-standard C++, array sizes must be fixed at compile-time. Some compilers accept this as an extension by default. A simple fix is to replace the variable type with `auto` (which happens to make Clang happy), but it would be better to just compute the indices by hand. Also pass `-pedantic-errors` to your compiler to outright reject this non-standard stuff.

Comment: As part of your problem, you try to create variable-length arrays, and [C++ doesn't really have them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). If you want to use run-time variable-length arrays, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai GCC accepts this but Clang rejects. Their VLA implementations in C++ mode are slightly different it seems. I bet OP is unknowingly using Clang...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh my. VLAs and c-arrays are too confusing for me. Deleted confused comments ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There isn't a simple way to fix this with `std::vector`. You either pass a vector of vectors (which is a bad thing), or just a vector (which doesn't help with index calculations any more than a plain pointer, and adds annoyance for the caller (can't pass other containers anymore)). There's probably some clever solution using `mdspan` (either inside the function, or as a parameter).

Comment: Why are you writing yet another matrix multiplication routine?

Comment: This is not how you deal with multi-dimensional arrays. You use a single 1d array and compute offsets into that. Such computations are annoying (and error prone) to repeat so you wrap that in a class. See existing libraries for examples, e.g. Eigen.

Answer (score -3):

Well, it seems that this is non-standard C++, GCC accepts this but Clang rejects. I'm using GCC to avoid this problem. The issues related to compilers always frustrate me, especially now that I am still a beginner.